# How do you make debugging one web project dependent on running another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, vs-web-site-project

I have multiple web projects in one solution with several requiring others to be running in order to function. For example, project A may require projects E and F to be running and Project B may require Projects F, G, and H to be running.

Is there a way to have visual studio manage these dependencies so that when I go to debug project A, projects E & F also starts automatically? I know I can set multiple startup projects in order to make sure both projects startup when I go to debug, but this means that when I go to run project A, I need to have memorized which other projects also need to be set to startup and the same for all of the rest of the projects, each of which has different requirements for running.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe remove runnable projects to separate solutions, and class libraries to one or more solutions which you will reference when needed...
This way, you will run what you need and when needed only, and reduce number of references you have...
Then, you may run everything manually, or create some automated build system with, for example, dashboard app, which will build and you can chose what to run and what do you need active...

Also, keep project specific code inside a project solution, and move shared class libraries to shared solutions, in order to keep your code clean and not duplicated...

If done well, this could lead to lots of code decoupling and simpler app diagram...

Answer (score -1):

Go to your solution and right click on the main one and select `Set Startup projects...` then pick `Multiple startup projects`and if you want to projectB runs before projectA then just move it using the arrows so projectB is above to project A

If needing more assistance, you can also check this official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019

Comment: I'm already aware that you can set multiple projects to start and even control their start order. The goal is to have this managed automatically in a project where project A may require projects E and F to be running, but project B may require projects F, G, and H to be running. And various other projects that require others running. Just trying to find a way to reduce the amount of memorizing which projects require which others and the amount of time lost to manually searching through the project list to turn startup on and off.